# Change saved prices in different currency in one currency in MySql

Tags: phpmyadmin

We are creating an small app for our shopping store, which will show a report in graphical(bar chart) format. This report will show "Number of Coupon Vs price interval". That is, within price range how many number of coupon has been distributed among users.

As store has option to change currency, due to this, prices in database are saving according to currency set by admin. As result, entries in database has multiple currency values. So, we are facing problem to show reports in graphical form due to multiple currency. Given below is the following screen shot of what we have done:

[image]

As we can resolve this problem, by first by fetching entries from database and then convert them into selected currency before displaying graph. But this solution may be little time consuming and not an optimal method. So, we want to know that, can we do this directly by sql query like, if we first convert prices of all entries into selected currency and then compare with specified range??

My table has following structure:

Table_name: Products
col_prod_name,
col_price,
col_currency

Our query to fetch data according to specified range is:
select * from Products where col_price between 10 AND 50

Suppose, the above table has entries in INR and USD currency and admin selects USD. So, we want that query will convert all prices into selected currency(USD) and then compare with specified range so that the all report will be shown to user in USD currency.

Please anyone give me the solution of how can we resolve this problem??  Waiting for reply!